# HP Fortify scan on Multiple branch

Tags: scanf

Is there a way that we can run the HP fortify (SSC) scan on multiple branches without merging the issues and generate reports separately?

When we run the scan on Branch A (having issues 10), later run the scan on branch B (having issues 100); the next run in the branch A creating issues count as 110.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to use different buildIDs. You will get different FPR reports:

```
#cleaning phase
sourceanalyzer -clean

#parsing phase
sourceanalyzer -b branchA -cp lib/dependencyA.jar ....etc
sourceanalyzer -b branchB -cp lib/dependencyB.jar ....etc

#scanning phase
sourceanalyzer -b branchA -scan -f results_A.fpr
sourceanalyzer -b branchB -scan -f results_B.fpr
```